# jQuery validation condition based on elements selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have following input elements on my form and and validation form with jQuery validation plugin.

### HTML:

```
<form name='frmUsers' id='frmUsers' method='post' action='#'>
    <div>
        <input type='text' name='name' id='name' placeholder='Name' />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <input type='text' name='fixed_budget' id='fixed_budget' placeholder='Fixed budget' />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <select name='budget' id='budget'>
            <option value=''>Select your budget</option>
            <option value='1000'>1000</option>
            <option value='2000'>2000</option>
            <option value='3000'>3000</option>
            <option value='4000'>4000</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <input id='save' type='submit' value='Save' />
    </div>
</form>
```

### jQuery validation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#frmUsers").validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true
            },
                "fixed_budget": {
                required: true
            },
                "budget": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "name": {
                required: 'required'
            },
                "first_name": {
                required: 'required'
            },
                "last_name": {
                required: 'required'
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Now all elements are required fields but I have specific condition on `Fixed budget (text box) and budget (select box)`.

### For example:

When user click on submit, `fixed budget` and `budget` elements display with errors but (1) when user select any option on `budget`, set fixed budget field to not required. (2) when user input something on `fixed budget` set budget field to not required.

Here is my working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/85KR4/384/

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you do **not** need a `click` handler or a conditional to see if the form exists.  The plugin automatically captures the click and jQuery automatically ignores the code if the selector element does not exist.  http://jsfiddle.net/85KR4/385/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) when user select any option on budget, set fixed budget field to not required. (2) when user input something on fixed budget set budget field to not required.

In other words, you only require one of those two fields filled out.

Include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js) and use [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/).

```
rules: {
    name: {
        required: true
    },
    fixed_budget: {
        require_from_group: [1, ".requiredGroup"]
    },
    budget: {
        require_from_group: [1, ".requiredGroup"]
    }
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7om97gk8/**

**Note:**

1. Use `return false` within the `errorPlacement` function if you want to suppress messages.  Don't leave the function empty, as that's sloppy coding.

   ```
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      return false;
   },
   ```
2. Also, use the latest version of the plugin file as this will ensure the `require_from_group` method operates bug-free.
3. I don't understand why you are using the `messages` option when you've totally disabled these messages from displaying.  You can safely remove `messages` in this case.