# Jquery validation two inputs one is required listener

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, user-input

Im looking to get validate two input fields. Only one is required. The code I have works, but I am trying to get it to validate after one of the fields is filled in.

If I I tab over the field the error goes away. I would rather the error go away after the user fills in the info on said field.

### code:

```
$('#talent_form').validate({
  ignore:"",
  onfocusout: false,
  rules: {
    "talent_category":      "required",
    "talent_description":   "required",
    "city":                 "required",
    "first-name":           "required",
    "last-name":            "required",
    "email":                { required: true, validEmail: true },
    "uploadedfile":             {
      required: function(element) {
        return $("#text-link").val() == 0;
      }
    },
    "text-link":            {
      required: function(element) {
        return $("#uploadedfile").val() == 0; 
      }
    }
  },
  submitHandler : function(form) {
    form.submit();
        $("#talent_submit").html('submitting...');
    sendEventToGA('talent_submitted');
  }

});
```

### form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="talent_form" class="validate" action="uploader3.php" method="post">

  <div class="upload-fields">
    <div class="fileUpload home-cta btn btn-primary">
      <span>Upload</span>
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" class="upload"  multipart/>
      </div>
    <div class="file-link">
      <input type="text" class="file-upload" name="text-link" id="text-link" placeholder="Link">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

### problem:

[image]

the two fields that I am looking to have that done is between `uploadedfile` && `text-link`.
So to reiterate, If a user chooses to enter a text rather than a file, the error still shows on the file input field.

Comment: Show the relevant HTML of the form.

Comment: Also, if you don't want validation when the user tabs out of a field, then set `onfocusout` to `false`.

Comment: @Sparky thanks for that tid bit.  I edited my script and test.  Still have that issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear, however, I think you have two fields and you want to "require" that the user to fill out one or the other.  In that case, this might help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33270061/594235